# Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/

Tags: java, android

**Java file:**

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root
>   that contains
>   /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.chandan.halo/files/Pictures/JPEG_20170216_233855_-96483920.jpg
>
> error in line Uri photouURI=......

```
if (photoFile != null) {
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                        "com.chandan.halo.fileprovider",
                        photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 300);
            }
```

file_paths.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/com.chandan.halo/Pictures" />
    <!--<external-cache-path name="name" path="path" />-->
</paths>
```

**manifest.xml:**

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.chandan.halo.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </provider>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
<external-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/com.chandan.halo/Pictures" />
```

with:

```
<external-files-path name="my_images" path="Pictures" />
```

Comment: @ChandanBera: I cannot explain that, assuming that you are on a current version of the support libraries (e.g., 25.1.1). [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Camera/FileProvider) demonstrates the use of `FileProvider` with `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, though I think that I use a different file location.